# Track value change in dropdowns across across application using a directive

Tags: angularjs

There is a requirement to track the value change in a Dropdown throughout the application as soon as the the existing Dropdown value is changed.

Working on Angular.js and it provides with a `ng-change` which do exactly the same.

But `ng-change` has to be called from all the `<select>` in HTML and if there is any specific functionality has to be taken care for particular Dropdowns then it can be called in `ng-change`. So I want to write a directive which gets called as soon as the value is changed.

Is this possible? And how do I make sure directive gets called before `ng-change`?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Take a look about directives `priority`.

[Angular $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The **priority** is used to sort the directives before their **compile** functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical **priority** are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is **0**.